# Error inflating class fragment: Line 10 xml

Tags: java, android, xml, fragment, slidingpanelayout

I'm building an app with a sliding pane and im having trouble running it. I am keep having FCs. I am fairly new to android development.

```
package com.anshikka.datagushalpha;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

SlidingPaneLayout pane;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    pane = (SlidingPaneLayout) findViewById(R.id.sp);
    pane.setPanelSlideListener(new PaneListener());

    if (!pane.isSlideable()) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.leftpane).setHasOptionsMenu(false);
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.rightpane).setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
}

public class PaneListener extends FragmentActivity implements SlidingPaneLayout.PanelSlideListener {
    public PaneListener()
    {}

    @Override
    public void onPanelClosed(View view) {
        System.out.println("Panel closed");

        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.leftpane);
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.rightpane);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPanelOpened(View view) {
        System.out.println("Panel opened"); 
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.leftpane).setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.rightpane).setHasOptionsMenu(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPanelSlide(View view, float arg1) {
        System.out.println("Panel sliding");
    }

}
}
```

Here's my XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sp">



<!-- Left side pane. (Master) -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/leftpane" android:name="com.anshikka.datagushalpha.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="190dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class:com.
    android:layout_gravity="left" />


<!-- Right side page. (Slave) -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/rightpane" android:name="com.anshikka.datagushalpha.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="350dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right" android:layout_weight="1" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

Here is my Log

```
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203): Process: com.anshikka.datagushalpha, PID: 15203
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.anshikka.datagushalpha/com.anshikka.datagushalpha.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at com.anshikka.datagushalpha.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     ... 9 more
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.anshikka.datagushalpha.MainActivity that is not a Fragment
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:585)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4778)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     ... 19 more
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
02-22 14:27:01.624: E/AndroidRuntime(15203):     ... 23 more
```

Comment: Is com.anshikka.datagushalpha.MainActivity a fragment or rather an activity (which it would seem from the name)? You cannot use activities as fragments. Activities contain fragments.

Comment: With that name attribute you are trying to tell both Fragments they are the MainActivity. As your Logcat tells you, MainActivity is no Fragment but a FragmentActivity. You need new Fragments, you wont be able to invoke MainActivity on itself.
Also whats that class:com.?
And have you closed the <android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout> you opened?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your XML layout file is malformed.  Just remove the line with `class:com.` and see if it goes successfully.

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/leftpane" android:name="com.anshikka.datagushalpha.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="190dp" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class:com. <===== THIS LINE IS UNNECESSARY
    android:layout_gravity="left" />
```

Comment: I removed that. But i'm still getting the same FC error. Is there anything else?

Comment: I looked at your error message more closely and found `Trying to instantiate a class com.anshikka.datagushalpha.MainActivity that is not a Fragment`.  Right, your MainActivity is an Activity and not a Fragment.  You need to define a Fragment and refer that from XML.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem adding the fullname of the activity you are parsing to the fragment into the manifest, including the com. path, like:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.mainproject.PaneTest"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Before was:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".PaneTest"

        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Hope this helps!!

Here is a great code:
http://www.javaexperience.com/add-slidingpanelayout-to-your-android-application/